# Date-picker opening keyboard on change event

Tags: cordova, meteor, datepicker, hybrid-mobile-app, date-format

Working on hybrid meteor app and using datepicker to show dates in format MM-DD-YYYY. As datepicker works on input type='text' and meteor changes all this to cordova apk which results in whenever I focus in datepicker input it is not opening mobile phones calender but datepicker's calender and also opening keyboard as it is of type='text', which is right behaviour I guess but I do not want that keyboard to open.

If I use input type="date" and will not use datepicker then mobile apk will open native calender but here format I need which is MM-DD-YYYY is not possible.

What should I do??
Thanks in advance!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could add an attribute called `readonly` with value true to date input element so that it doesn't open your keyboad but it will open the `datepicker` instead.

Something like this.

```
<input type="text" class="form-control datepicker" readonly="true">
```

Hope this solves your problem. :)